# What is the best way to hash an unsorted collection of value-pairs

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have some data structure that look like this:

```
struct Server {
    let size : Int
    let capacity : Int
}

struct Slot {
    let row : Int
    let position : Int
}

struct Configuration {
    let computers : Array<(Server, Slot)>

    public var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make the Configuration Hashable so that each configuration that have identical server installed in the same slots have the same hashValue.

What would be the best approach to do so?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This may helps you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531906/calculate-unique-integer-representing-a-pair-of-integers. You may adapt it for 4 integers, provided that your size, capacity, row and position don't cover the integer set. I suppose size may not be random, etc. Use only meaningful bits to construct a unique integer. This one may also helps you https://gist.github.com/badboy/6267743